# Replace the value of one column from another column in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below

```
+---+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |indexes     |arrayString                                                           |
+---+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2  |1,3         |[WrappedArray(3, Str3), WrappedArray(1, Str1)]                        |
|1  |2,4,3       |[WrappedArray(2, Str2), WrappedArray(3, Str3), WrappedArray(4, Str4)] |
|0  |1,2,3       |[WrappedArray(1, Str1), WrappedArray(2, Str2), WrappedArray(3, Str3)] |
+---+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i want to loop through arrayString and get the first element as index and second element as String. Then replace the indexes with String corresponding to the index in arrayString. I want an output like below.

```
+---+---------------+
|id |replacedString |
+---+---------------+
|2  |Str1,Str3      |
|1  |Str2,Str4,Str3 |
|0  |Str1,Str2,Str3 |
+---+---------------+
```

I tried using the below udf function.

```
  val replaceIndex = udf((itemIndex: String, arrayString: Seq[Seq[String]]) => {
      val itemIndexArray = itemIndex.split("\\,")
    arrayString.map(i => {
      itemIndexArray.updated(i(0).toInt,i(1))
    })
    itemIndexArray
  })
```

This is giving me error and i am not getting my desired output. Is there any other way to achieve this. I cant use explode and join as i want the indexes replaced with string without losing the order.

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `udf` as below to get the required result, Convert to the Array of `array` to `map` and find the index as a key in `map`.

```
val replaceIndex = udf((itemIndex: String, arrayString: Seq[Seq[String]]) => {
  val indexList = itemIndex.split("\\,")
  val array = arrayString.map(x => (x(0) -> x(1))).toMap
  indexList map array mkString ","
})

dataframe.withColumn("arrayString", replaceIndex($"indexes", $"arrayString"))
.show( false)
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+--------------+
|id |indexes|arrayString   |
+---+-------+--------------+
|2  |1,3    |Str1,Str3     |
|1  |2,4,3  |Str2,Str4,Str3|
|0  |1,2,3  |Str1,Str2,Str3|
+---+-------+--------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, this answers help me. Can you please explain what is happening in this line  indexList map array mkString ","

Comment: That is equivalent to `indexList.map(array).mkString(",")` and  `indexList.map(i => array.get(i)).mkString(",")` I think this makes you easier to understand

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer and explanation